# Tablayout & viewpager scale and translate

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have Tablayout and Viewpager on the main Android activity. Its size is about half of the screen. In one of the Tab page having a listview (extends ListFragment)

Is there any way to resize and translate the Tablayout and Viewpager while scrolling the listview.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with parallax effect. see the link below to have this kind of implemetation.

[Parrallax effect link](http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/)

Answer (score 0):

check this example. I hope it help.

[Effect using coordinatorlayout](https://github.com/GovindaPaliwal/tablayout-with-imageslider)